# How to allow authenticated cross-domain calls in an SP 2016 on-prem scenario?

Tags: rest, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, cross-domain, oauth

In an on-premises scenario I need to call SharePoint 2016 REST services (via XHR) from JavaScript. The calls will originate from a host *different* from the SharePoint host. To allow these calls I need to configure CORS on the SharePoint side. The `Authorization` header must be sent along for this request to be authenticated.

For the `Authorization` header to be included in my REST calls I need the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header sent by SharePoint to contain a specific host name (specifically not '*' as this prevents the header from being sent.)

**Unfortunately in SharePoint 2016 the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header seems to be hard-coded to '*' according to this blog post:**

https://thesharepointfarm.com/2017/03/cors-http-headers-in-sharepoint-server-2016/

Quote from the blog post:

> Since SharePoint only accepts OAuth for CORS requests, and not user
>   authentication such as cookies, Cross Site Request Forgery is a
>   non-issue as origin validation does not need to take place when using
>   OAuth. As such, setting Allow-Cross-Origin-Request to ‘*’ becomes a
>   non-issue.

Now the question is, how to deal with this situation?

More specifically:

- Can CORS for SharePoint 2016 be configured in a way to explicitly use host names for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`?
- If this is not possible: how to use OAuth in SP 2016 on-prem from JavaScript? Which authentification endpoint must be used? Which flows are supported? We are not talking about an add-in here, but about plain JS running in another host.
- Is some kind of add-in registration (appregnew.aspx) and/or add-in package (dummy?) necessary for this to work?
  Note: no server-to-server communication is needed. Only plain JS XHR from the browser.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Please provide steps to configure url rewrite for CORS. any article available for this.?

Comment: Here it is: 
https://support.communardo.de/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=67635639

not verified

Comment: @RajavarmanN Yep, this is it.

Comment: @RajavarmanN Can you please provide the steps on how to achieve this using URL Rewrite , the link provided above is broken it seems ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evantually we successfully used the [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) module, evaluating and inserting CORS headers when requests come in. This is happening outside SharePoint, as part of IIS request processing.

Comment: So, just to be clear, setting headers manually does not work, using the official IIS module for CORS does not work, but setting a Rewrite module rule to modify the headers does work?  I guess it must run after whatever core Sharepoint logic is forcibly setting `ACA-Origin: *` ?

Comment: I think yes. The Rewrite module modifies what SharePoint generated..

Comment: Ugh.  It sounds like this might be the only real solution for on-prem.  I was waiting for an official answer from someone on the PnP/SP team but it's been a while and nothing yet.  (All the solutions in the docs require you to authenticate through `login.microsoftonline.com` -- not much help for a farm that's not on the internet!)